# Mail signing and encrypting with Apache Camel

Tags: email, encryption, apache-camel

I want to sign and encrypt my mail.

My current camel version is 2.13.0.

Is there a camel feature which I can use for this purpose?

Body is plain text therefore XMLDSig or so cannot be used.

Expected result should be a mail with these headers:

- Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name="smime.p7m"; smime-type=enveloped-data
- Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: I can't speak about the sign and encryption part but for e-mail you can use http://camel.apache.org/mail.html. I guess since the message is treated as plain text you can use any sign and encryption library you want and set the content-type and encoding.

Comment: I use currently the standard camel mail component.
I believe I must create a javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage with body and attachments stored as javax.mail.Multipart. This MimeMessage can be signed and encrypted.
When I add the whole MimeMessage as body from the exchange and send it with smtp it should hopefully work.

Comment: There is a Camel component specifically for Crypto digital signatures: http://camel.apache.org/crypto-digital-signatures.html. And another link for all security concerns in Camel http://camel.apache.org/security.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Camel user, but I was curious and played around with it. What you want is S/MIME signing and encryption. This is currently unavailable, but there is a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8405) for it which never got any response since it was created in February 2015. Camel has a MIME-Multipart data format, PGP encryption (but only symmetric), Sign/Verify (without encryption) - but I see no way to combine them in order to really get a valid S/MIME envelope for a signed + encrypted e-mail. Besides, PGP is not S/MIME and vice versa.

I do know how to compose and send such e-mail via JavaMail + BouncyCastle library, I even have sample code for it. Theoretically you could create the MIME message via JavaMail + BouncyCastle and then use Camel to send it or create your own S/MIME endpoint or data format (at least one-way for marshalling and skip unmarshalling if you do not need it). But out of the box I have not found a way to do it.

---

**Update:**

Even if I put a preconfigured signed & encrypted MIME part on the input endpoint and do this...

```java
.setHeader("From", simple("sender@web.de"))
.setHeader("To", simple("recipient@web.de"))
.setHeader("Subject", simple("Signed & encrypted"))
.setHeader("Content-Type", simple("application/pkcs7-mime; name=\"smime.p7m\"; smime-type=enveloped-data"))
.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", simple("base64"))
```

... and the mail is sent, mail clients like Thunderbird cannot really disiplay the mail because the Camel mail endpoint overwrites the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` by a value of `7bit`. There is [another ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7536) for this issue, but also unresolved since June 2014. So for the time being you cannot even use the mail endpoint to send the message after you have built it via JavaMail and BouncyCastle. You even have to send it by yourself (also very simple via JM + BC, but annoying). So presently you cannot really use the Camel infrastructure because endpoints and data formats are unfit for S/MIME message composition.

Comment: I accept your answer because you pointed out that signing and encryption is not available in camel. I described my solution in an own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem for sending.

I created a new MimeMessage with all required parameters like *from*, *recipient*, *subject* and content (Multipart with body and attachments).

With BouncyCastle I [signed](http://www.borelly.net/cb/docs/javaBC-1.4.8/smime/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMESignedGenerator.html) and [encrypted](http://www.borelly.net/cb/docs/javaBC-1.4.8/smime/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator.html) this MimeMessage.

I set the resulting MimeMessage as body and sent it with standard camel mail endpoint. All required parameters will be selected from the MimeMessage itself and not from the exchange headers.

For receiving I will use also the camel mail standard but with the parameter *mapMailMessage=false* that I can process the received *javax.mail.Message* itself without preprocessing. For decrypting I will also use BouncyCastle.

Comment: So basically you just do what I described in my answer. I am glad I could help. But one question in return: If you send the message as described, can you read it with standard mail clients like Thunderbird or Outlook or Lotus Notes? If you can just read them with your own homebrew Camel solution, IMO they are not worth a lot in the real e-mail world.

Comment: Yes, I can read them with Outlook and Gmail without problems. I also sent signed mails without encryption and they are also valid.
My goal was to create valid signed and encrypted mails otherwise it would be useless for me. Signing and encryption is done from BouncyCastle depending on RFC´s therefore it should be accepted from every mail clients.

Comment: Very interesting. Would you mind posting a little code snippet about how you did it? I like to learn from you, tit for tat. :-) I would like to try it in my own example and replace the maual sending part. Thanks in advance.